# Order by related object attribute in Django/Python

Tags: python, django, sorting, django-queryset

I have a static Object called `Module`. One of the attributes for a Module object is a `'name'`. I have a database table called `Section` that saves the Module key in a column.

**I'd like to fetch the objects from that table and sort by the name of the Module they are related with.**

Most of the time, when I reference the Module object, it's like this: `section.module.module_object.name`

The model is:

```
class Section(models.Model):
    page = models.ForeignKey(Page)
    module = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=50, choices=[(k, '%s %s' % (s.service, s.name)) for k, s in MODULES.iteritems()])
```

I've tried this:

```
navigation_links = sorted(navigation_links.values(), key=lambda m: m['module'].module_object.name)
```

but I get the error `AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'module_object'`

UPDATE: Here is the module object:

```
class Module(object):

    def __init__(self, key, name):
        self.key = key
        self.name = name

# ... list of a lot of ALL_MODULES

#dict of the above list
MODULES = dict([(s.key, s) for s in ALL_MODULES])
```

Comment: @DrTyrsa - I'd like to fetch the objects from that table and sort by the name of the Module they are related with. But those two approaches are giving me errors.

Comment: `module` field is just a string. You need to retrieve your object somehow. Of course you can't do it at DB level.

Comment: @DrTyrsa So it seems like I need to grab them from the db, and then sort by the attribute of the module_object. That's what I'm not sure how to do.

Comment: What task are you trying to achieve? Why do you need to use some object instead of normal Django model. What's the purpose of the object? What interface does it have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code I infer that `MODULES` is a dictionary of your Module objects, indexed by value by which they are saved in the database. These objects have a `name` property, so if you modify your example to fetch the object from this dictionary by saved name, you should get what you need:

```
navigation_links = sorted(navigation_links.values(), 
                          key=lambda m: MODULES[m['module']].name)
```

Of course, this is all based on my guesses about your code. If this doesn't work, please provide more information about `section` and `module_object` variables.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the lack of info. MODULES is a dict of a static object, not database related. I've added that structure above. Then, Section references the key of the Module Object.